# How many different sets of positive integers $(a, b, c, d)$ are there such that $a \lt b \lt c \lt d$ and $a + b + c + d = 41$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-proofs, linear-diophantine-equations

Is there a general formula which I can use to calculate this and if it's with proof or reasoning would be great as well. Even if you could please solve this $4$-variable ordered set of positive integers case would be a great help indeed. Sorry I am weak in this topic.

Thanks Robert for your pointers in modifying it to
$(4\times1) + (3\times2) + (2\times3) + (1\times4) = 41$, where there are no additional constraints on $x_i$

To solve this must do it manually by cases or is there a short way of calculating it using "Bars and Stars" (of which I am aware of the method)? The answer given is $321$.

But when I calculate it like this it doesn't seem to match the answer:
imagine the new given equation as containing $(4+3+2+1) = 10$$x_i$'s individually so as equivalent to finding the number of positive integer solutions for $b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_{10} = 41$ which is $C(41 - 1, 10 - 1) = C(40, 9)$. Now since we have $4x_1$'s that are identical, we need to divide this by $4!$ (for its permutations of "overcounting") and similarly divide next by $3!$ (for $3x_2$'s that are equal), and $2!$ for the $2x_3$'s that are equal. How is my approach wrong here? anybody, please help me? Thanks again

As per Robert's transformation with Anil's suggestion of the generating functions method, here's my work on it:

I actually used an online calculator called "Sage Math" to do this via this website:

https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.01.html

With these modifications

$f(x)=(1-x^4)^{-1}\times(1-x^3)^{-1}\times(1-x^2)^{-1}\times(1-x)^{-1}$

show(taylor($f,x,0,33$))

And have gotten the verification  that $321$ is indeed the answer after some tedious algebra (please note that since we are looking for the coefficient of $x^41$ in the expansion Anil wrote which has $x^(4+3+2+1) = x^10$ factored outside meaning in the remaining Newton's Binomial Expansions with negative exponent, we only need to determine the coefficient of $x^(41-10)= x^31$ in it which is "$321$" as the answer suggested (please see image below):

[image: Sage Math Expansion]

Comment: Since the result is odd, the set contains either 1 or 3 odds. Starting at $\frac{41}{4}\approx 10$ I would try to build the set then figure out how many there are.

Comment: This is the same as the number of solutions in positive integers of $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+x_4=41$, where there are no additional constraints on $x_i$.  The equivalence is demonstrated by $x_1=a, x_2=b-a, x_3=c-b, x_4=d-c$.  I suspect this is easier to solve because you no longer have to worry about order.  Please **edit the question** to provide your thoughts toward arriving at a solution.  For example, do you know how to solve the problem if the variables *aren't* required to be in increasing order?

Comment: Alternative approach to the comment of @RobertShore is that by [Stars and Bars theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/), the number of solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 41 ~: ~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z^+}$$ is $~\displaystyle \binom{40}{3}.~$  To this, you would have to deduct the number of solutions where **exactly** three of the four variables are equal and also deduct solutions where **exactly** two of the four variables are equal.  Note that since $41$ is an odd number, you can't have all $4$ numbers equal or have two pairs of $2$ equal numbers.

Comment: @user2661923 That significantly overcounts the number of solutions, though. The solutions with four distinct integers are each counted four times, those with two equal integers are counted thrice, and those with thee equal integers are counted twice. $\binom{40}{3}$ counts the ways to pull three different numbers in the range $[1,40]$, because pulling three fixes the fourth. But pulling $(1,2,3), (1,2,35), (1,3,35), (2,3,35)$ are all actually the same solution.

Comment: @EricSnyder Very good point.  My carelessness for overlooking this.  However, the Stars and Bars approach is still viable, as long as you assign the appropriate *over-counting adjustment factor* to each pertinent subset of solutions.  For example, when enumerating the number of solutions with exactly two equal numbers, you have that $c$ will range through $\{1,2,\cdots,20\}$, and the number of solutions to $~x_3 + x_4 = 41 - 2c~$ is $~40 - 2c.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: @EricSnyder You also have the further complication that for $~c \leq 13~$, the correct enumeration here is $~39 - 2c,~$ since you don't want *triples* here (i.e. solutions with exactly three of the numbers equal).  Then, to this overall enumeration, you have to apply the adjustment factor of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\binom{4}{2}}.$

Comment: @EricSnyder On balance however, because of the complications involved in trying to salvage the Stars and Bars approach, complications that I originally overlooked, I now think that your original approach is significantly better.  In fact, if I hadn't overlooked the complications, I would not have even mentioned the Stars and Bars approach in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we solve the problem without the condition $a<b<c<d$ then the answer is $40\choose3$.

Now we want to count the number of sets with at least $2$ equal variables.

Note that all $4$ of them can't be equal, because if they are then their sum should be divisible by $4$.

**Case $1$ :** Exactly $2$ of them are equal.

We need to solve the equation $$2x_1+x_2+x_3=41 : x_1,x_2,x_3\in \mathbb{N}$$

where $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are pairwise distinct.

If $x_1 = k$ then the number solutions is ${41-2k-1\choose1} = 41-2k-1$, for any $1\leq k\leq13$ we have counted $2$ extra solutions ($x_2 = k$ and $x_3=k$).

Thus the number of solutions for this case is ${4\choose2}(38+36+\dots + 2 - 26) = {4\choose2}2(19+18+\dots + 1 - 13) = 2124$

**Case 2 :** Exactly $3$ of them are equal.

We calculate the number of solutions like Case $1$.

The number of solutions for this case is $13{4\choose3} = 52$.

So there are ${40\choose3} - (52 + 2124) = 7704$ solutions.

For every pairwise distinct $a,b,c,d$
there is exactly 1 permutation such that $a<b<c<d$. we counted each set $(a,b,c,d)$, $4!$ times.

So the answer is $\frac{7704}{4!}=321$.

Comment: Thank you! I think this method is the most practical to count and do within a competition setting, impressive!

Answer (score 5):

As has been suggested by @Robert Shore, transform the problem to

$4x_1 + 3x_2 +2x_3 + x_4 = 41,\; x_i \in N$

Now when multinomials in $x$ are multiplied together, the exponents get added up, so if we multiply

$(x^4 +x^8 +....\infty)(x^3+x^6+...\infty)(x^2+x^4+....\infty)(x+x^2+....\infty)$

we will find the answer in the coefficient of $x^{41}$, which represents all possible combos where the sum of the exponents in the multiplied terms is $41$.

We can simplify the expression to $\left(\frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cdot\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}\cdot\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$.

Multiplying it out gives the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+expansion+at+x+%3D+0+of+x%5E10%2F%28%281-x%5E4%29%281-x%5E3%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%29%29++++++++++++++++++++&key=9zakc) of $\;\boxed{321}$

This is a simple example of *generating functions* of whose rudimentary uses you could learn bit by bit

Comment: Thank you for this. I understand the generating functions way for this where the power is actually 41 not 141. But I was more keen if there was a way to count this part using stars and bars? Because the generating function expansion is gonna use Newton's Binomial Theorem and some tedious algebra to complete

Comment: Thanks for the heads up re inadvertent typo ! From the hints already provided by others, do you still need assistance ?

Comment: Thank you Anil for asking but unless someone has some different method, yours has been very helpful too (but I am  aware of this actually)

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, by assuming $a=x_1, b=x_1+x_2, c=x_1+x_2+x_3$ and $d=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$, the problem transforms into finding the number of sets $(x_1, x_2,x_3, x_4)$ of positive integers such that: $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=41.$

It is very easy to note that $1 \leq x_4 \leq8$ because $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq1.$

Moreover, observe that, for a positive integer $k$;

**if $x_1+2x_2=2k$, then there are $k-1$ pairs of $(x_1, x_2)$ satisfying the equation;**

and **if $x_1+2x_2=2k+1$, then there are $k$ pairs of $(x_1, x_2)$ satisfying the equation.**

Now, with the help of the information above, we can use the approach below, which is limited to very simple calculations in spite of considering $8$ cases.

---

Case $1$: $x_4=1$.

$$(x_4, x_3)=(1,11) \implies x_1+2x_2=4 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,10) \implies x_1+2x_2=7 \implies 3 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,9) \implies x_1+2x_2=10 \implies 4 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,8) \implies x_1+2x_2=13 \implies 6 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,7) \implies x_1+2x_2=16 \implies 7 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,6) \implies x_1+2x_2=19 \implies 9 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,5) \implies x_1+2x_2=22 \implies 10 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=25 \implies 12 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=28 \implies 13 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=31 \implies 15 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(1,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=34 \implies 16 \ solutions;$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $96$.

---

Case $2$: $x_4=2.$
$$(x_4, x_3)=(2,10) \implies x_1+2x_2=3 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,9) \implies x_1+2x_2=6 \implies 2 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,8) \implies x_1+2x_2=9 \implies 4 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,7) \implies x_1+2x_2=12 \implies 5 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,6) \implies x_1+2x_2=15 \implies 7 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,5) \implies x_1+2x_2=18 \implies 8 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=21 \implies 10 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=24 \implies 11 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=27 \implies 13 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(2,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=30 \implies 14 \ solutions;\\$$

hence, in this case, the total number is $75$.

---

Case $3$: $x_4=3.$
$$(x_4, x_3)=(3,8) \implies x_1+2x_2=5 \implies 2 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,7) \implies x_1+2x_2=8 \implies 3 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,6) \implies x_1+2x_2=11 \implies 5 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,5) \implies x_1+2x_2=14 \implies 6 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=17 \implies 8 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=20 \implies 9 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=23 \implies 11 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(3,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=26 \implies 12 \ solutions;\\$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $56$.

---

Case $4$: $x_4=4.$
$$(x_4, x_3)=(4,7) \implies x_1+2x_2=4 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,6) \implies x_1+2x_2=7 \implies 3 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,5) \implies x_1+2x_2=10 \implies 4 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=13 \implies 6 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=16 \implies 7 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=19 \implies 9 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(4,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=22 \implies 10 \ solutions;\\$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $40$.

---

Case $5$: $x_4=5.$

$$(x_4, x_3)=(5,6) \implies x_1+2x_2=3 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(5,5) \implies x_1+2x_2=6 \implies 2 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(5,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=9 \implies 4 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(5,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=12 \implies 5 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(5,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=15 \implies 7 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(5,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=18 \implies 8 \ solutions;\\$$

hence, in this case, the total number is $27$.

---

Case $6$: $x_4=6.$

$$(x_4, x_3)=(6,4) \implies x_1+2x_2=5 \implies 2 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(6,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=8 \implies 3 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(6,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=11 \implies 5 \ solutions\\ (x_4, x_3)=(6,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=14 \implies 6 \ solutions;\\$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $16$.

---

Case $7$: $x_4=7.$

$$(x_4, x_3)=(7,3) \implies x_1+2x_2=4 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(7,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=7 \implies 3 \ solutions \\ (x_4, x_3)=(7,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=10 \implies 4 \ solutions;\\$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $8$.

---

Case $8$: $x_4=8.$

$$(x_4, x_3)=(8,2) \implies x_1+2x_2=3 \implies 1 \ solution \\ (x_4, x_3)=(8,1) \implies x_1+2x_2=6 \implies 2 \ solutions;$$
hence, in this case, the total number is $3$.

---

Finally, the answer is $96+75+56+40+27+16+8+3=321.$

Comment: Thank you Reza, this is a little enumerative but the details are certainly helpful to understand the solutions better. Kind efforts to list them all out!

Comment: @JonathanRamachandran You're welcome. Yes. I tried to write a very detailed solution. However, I believe this approach is very straightforward; as you may notice the computation is very easy, and the numbers of solutions in each case follow a pattern.

Comment: I actually also did this when I was first working out the problem; there's a definite pattern here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks some [info from OEIS](http://oeis.org/A008289), and some help from [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html), we have the following:

Let the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ **distinct** parts be $Q(n, k)$. Then $Q(n,k)$ has the recurrence:

$$Q(n,k) = Q(n-k, k) + Q(n-k, k-1)$$

where $Q(n,1) = 1, Q(n,0) = 0$.

---

If you prefer, we have a (possibly easier?) method: $Q(n, k) = P(n- \binom{k}{2}, k)$, where $P(n,k)$ has the recurrence:

$$P(n,k) = P(n-1, k-1) + P(n-k, k)$$

where $P(n,1) = P(n,n) = 1$. We'll want $P(35,4)$ of course. Either way, the OEIS link gives $Q(41,4) = P(35,4) = 321$.

---

If you *must* have a closed-form function, [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) has you... "covered," in the loosest sense of the term, and only for $P(n,k)$ up to $k=4$. The function involved is

$$P(n,4) = \textstyle \frac1{864} \displaystyle \left\{ 3 \left(n+1 \right) \left[2n \left(n+2 \right)-13+9 \left(-1 \right)^n \right] - 96 \cos \frac{2 \pi n}{3}+ \\ \left( 108 \left(-1 \right)^ \left(n/2 \right) \right) \big(\bmod \left(n+1,2 \right) \big)+32 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right)\right\}$$

And yes, for $n=35$ it does in fact evaluate to $321$.

Comment: Thank you Eric, that's very helpful and insightful especially the recurrence relation which can be used to calculate manually easier in say competition settings.